# Index error при использовании Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, веб-скрейпинг

При выполнении первой части кода, - все работает. При выполнении второй части кода, тоже се работает. Но при выполнении всего кода возникает IndexError, код выполняется и появляется ошибка
`Index error: list index out of range` в строке `namesBanks = soup.find("div", ...`.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как избежать ошибки.

Код:

```
url = 'https://canadianpreferredshares.ca/'
response = requests.get(url)
response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

dataTest = []
dataAll = []

dataNames = []
dataLink = []
data = []


for a in range(0, 3): #исправить на 53
    namesBanks = soup.find("div", class_="et_pb_code_inner").findAll("td", class_="issuerLinks")[a].text
    linksBanks = soup.find("div", class_="et_pb_code_inner").findAll("a")[a].get('href')
    #dataTest.append([namesBanks, linksBanks])
    # url2 = linksBanks
    # response = requests.get(url2)
    # response.text
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    dataNames.append([namesBanks])
    dataLink.append([linksBanks])
    string = ''
    for o in dataLink:
        string += o[0]

for k in dataLink:
url2 = string
response = requests.get(url2)
response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', class_='sortable sticky')

for employee_data in table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = employee_data.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    symbols = row.findAll("td")[0].text
    prices = row.findAll("td")[1].text
    high = row.findAll("td")[2].text
    low = row.findAll("td")[3].text
    fixedRateBase = row.findAll("td")[4].text
    current = row.findAll("td")[5].text
    name = row.findAll("td")[6].text
    nameLinks = row.find("a").get('href')

    data.append([symbols, prices, high, low, fixedRateBase, current, name, nameLinks])
data.insert(0, namesBanks)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю в цикле вы указываете диапазоном от 0 до 3, предполагая что у вас есть 100 банков на сайте, потом после каждой иттерации вы получаете временную переменную "a" и хотите найти этот индекс в массиве, но если у вас на странице всего 50 банков, то и массив соберётся из 50 индексов, поэтому при получении 51 индекса вы получаете ошибку, в вашем случае намного лучше будет сначала собрать все записи и потом уже по ним производить поиск

```
banks_list = soup.find("div",class_="et_pb_code_inner").findAll('td',class_="issuerLinks")
for bank in banks_list:
    dataNames.append(bank.text)
    dataLink.append(bank.find('a').get('href'))
```